# Simple alternative to Powered Explicit Guidance for orbital insertion?

Tags: launch, orbital-maneuver, launch-sequence, orbital

Say you're playing space ops engineer and want to simulate an orbital insertion---but you're petrified by the calculations needed to get the coefficients of the linear tangent law behind Powered Explicit Guidance (PEG).

You have a good feedback controller to point your rocket where you tell it to point, but you don't know the best place to point it because you can't do the math for PEG.

How would you approximate your target pitch angle as a function of time so that you can arrive from your initial post-MECO pitch to a final zero pitch at the correct altitude and velocity?

I'm essentially saying I'm OK with dropping the optimization part of the PEG algorithm and just figuring out *some* pitch program---*any* pitch program---that will take me from where I am at some time t post-MECO to orbital insertion.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 6):

I have also been unable to implement PEG and struggled to find an adequate approach in my orbital launch sim.

I have tried simply steering proportional to fraction-of-orbital-altitude-reached in the orbital insertion phase. I have tried various forms of quadratic guidance (inspired by the the Apollo LM's landing guidance). None have gotten good results.

At present, I use a time-scheduled pitch program for the early phase of launch and a fixed-coefficient LTG for the insertion phase, and tune the LTG coefficients manually for each launcher, which is extremely tedious. I've considered setting the sim up to automatically search for the best LTG coefficients, but haven't done it.

I think the right answer is to buckle down and really understand and implement PEG, but I haven't been able to do so myself. Section 4.2.1 of the  [Ascent Guidance, Navigation, and Flight Control Workbook](https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/JSC%20GNC%20ASC%202102%20Ascent%20Guidance%20and%20Navigation%20and%20Flight%20Control%20Workbook.pdf) that Organic Marble dug up looks like it might be helpful in that effort.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in, @RusselBorogove! It's a tough thing to do, huh? Dumb question, but what is LTG? Also, do you do the gravity turn using a precomputed program, or do you use a feedback controller to hold angle of attack at zero? I've read the Saturn V used a precomputed pitch program for the gravity turn (not just the pitchover), but why wouldn't they use a feedback controller to actively keep angle of attack at zero---do you know?

Comment: @Alex they were worried that active gimbaling of the F-1s was not safe. In particular, they were worried that if some strong disturbance (e.g. wind shear) would induce such a strong control reaction that the structural integrity of the vehicle would be  compromised. So instead they recorded the deviation from intended path and corrected it only just before orbital insertion.

Comment: LTG = linear tangent guidance.

Comment: @Ludo: Oh wow, I never knew. Is active gimballing still a concern? Now I wonder if newer rockets like the Falcon 9 avoid it too. Any clue?

Comment: Ah! Thanks, @RussellBorogove. I do know what that is. I wasn't connecting the dots.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you can guess your coefficients and simulate, then pick better guesses and simulate, then repeat until you converge on some reasonable numbers. It's the poor man's way, ha ha, but if it works and you're out of practical options... then guess-and-check is your friend.

Comment: Shuttle also used a "canned" trajectory for first stage with PEG only starting at solid rocket booster separation.

Comment: I think Ludo meant to refer to closed loop active steering, not gimbaling per se. Gimbaling would be necessary to achieve the fixed guidance program.

Comment: There's a pretty lucid explanation of PEG in section 4.2.1 of this document: https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/JSC%20GNC%20ASC%202102%20Ascent%20Guidance%20and%20Navigation%20and%20Flight%20Control%20Workbook.pdf The document is old and there are some differences with how it worked in the latter part of the program - the whole TFAIL thing was removed when the TAL abort came about - but it's pretty informative.

Comment: That does look interesting.

Comment: You could try looking at my old MechJeb PEG code:  https://github.com/lamont-granquist/MechJeb2/blob/lcg/PEGAS2/MechJeb2/MechJebModulePEGController.cs#L562-L830=

Comment: I'd note that there's a lot of commented out code there that I was playing with for various different reasons.  Some things like TargetMode.ORBIT I didn't know what I was doing and are busted.  All of it is written with KSP's left handed system so watch those cross products and signs of any angles (which might also be degrees).

Comment: You may also be interested in https://oa.upm.es/39534/1/DANIEL_MONTERO_YEBOLES.pdf (search for PEG) along with https://www.icas.org/ICAS_ARCHIVE/ICAS2012/PAPERS/611.PDF